# How to extract the rows that contain only 1 "=" by using REGEXP in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, regex

Suppose I have a table named "t1" which contains a column named "ID" which has the following records

```
abcde=1=2
qwert=3
hhhhj=9
zxcv=5=8
```

How can I extract the records that contain only 1 "=" sign by using REGEXP in MySQL?

I've tried

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE ID REGEXP '\\w*=\\w*=\\w*';  -- returns no records 
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE ID REGEXP '\\w*=\\w*';       -- returns all 4 records
```

I expected the first query to return the records which contains 2 "=", and the second query to return the records which contains only 1 "=".

What's wrong with my queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pretty simple solution without `REGEXP` would be

```
select * from table
where 
length(ID) - length(replace(ID,'=','')) = 1 ;
```

Some test cases

```
mysql>  select length('qwert=3') - length(replace('qwert=3','=','')) as diff;
+------+
| diff |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>  select length('zxcv=5=8') - length(replace('zxcv=5=8','=','')) as diff;
+------+
| diff |
+------+
|    2 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE ID REGEXP '^[^=]*=[^=]*$';
```

Guess this should do it.See fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2ead/2/0

Comment: Maybe the reason it didn't work on my machine is because my MySQL version is 5.5.29, which is lower than 5.26.

Comment: @lyen did you try the new expression